# 3 Float Divs with overflow content to next div - html & css

Tags: css, css-float, overflow, html

I have 3 div's which is floated left, with a continuous content and fixed height, then overflowed content from the first div should be shifted to 2nd div and other overflowed content of 2nd div must shift into 3rd div. Right now I'm actually doing it manually by copy pasting it. But I want it to be dynamic, so that, If I enter content, its should get distributed into those 3 divs.

div structure:

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

css part:

```
.child{
    float:left;
    width:32%;
    padding:4px;
}
.bRight{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

below is the example which I am working on:

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/spkprav/QRsWQ/)

Please let me know, if someone has any solution.

Comment: So... You basically want columns?

Comment: Yes, with overflow content distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use column count property

http://jsfiddle.net/QRsWQ/7/

```
#main {
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -o-column-count:3;
    -ms-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
}
#main div {
    float:left;
    padding:4px;
    background:green;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all? -1

Comment: This isn't the result I'm asking for.

Comment: Now it doesn't support IE9, Opera, or Firefox.

Comment: Still doesn't support IE9, and it's VERY ugly when it overflows.

Comment: use -ms-column-count:3; for ie

Comment: IE, not required, Anyway thanks :), Here's the updated code of mine which is working. http://jsfiddle.net/spkprav/QRsWQ/6/